# how to use global variable in python's gevent

Tags: python, gevent

I'm new to `gevent` in python. I can achieve a multi threads logic as follow:

```
results = []
lock = threading.Lock()
threads = []

def fetch(page_num):
    data = get_some_data_from_url(page_num)

    lock.acquire()
    results.append(data)
    lock.release()

for i in range(1, 10):
    thread = threading.Thread(target=fetch, args=(i,))
    thread.start()
    threads.append(thread)

for thread in threads:
    thread.join()
```

How do I achieve this using `gevent`? I have known the`gevent.spawn()`function, but I can not do **Exclusive access** shared variable like `results` in the code. Ho do I do it?

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. Lock in gevent can't really do exclusive job. Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

you can avoid locks if you use something like [collections.deque](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque) as the type of `results` (you can push values in a deque object from different threads safely)